# PageList Component hierarchical data

Tags: sxa

Can anyone please suggest, how to display hierarchical data using PageList?

The Category items stored at: `/sitecore/system/Settings/Feature/MySite/Article Category`:
[image]

My articles stored at: `/sitecore/content/MyTenantFolder/Sites/MySite/Home/MySite/Articles`
[image]

The Category items used as a Treelist field type in Article data template: 
[image]

And I wanted to display data like:

[image]

Comment: Can you add some screenshots how the structure of your data looks like? It's hard to imagine how your data looks like reading just your description.
Page List is using Rendering Variants so I'm pretty sure that you will be able to display what you want (e.g. using Variant Query item)

Comment: The Category items stored at: /sitecore/system/Settings/Feature/ MySite/Article Category.  My articles stored at: /sitecore/content/MyTenantFolder/Sites/MySite/Home/MySite/Articles. I tried pagelist with Redering Variants (Variant query) but it's only showing Categories not Articles inside that.

Comment: I am not able to attach the screen shot. For me it's just showing plain text not rich text box.Is there any way to attach the screen shots?

Comment: @AmitKumar you have to edit your original question. You can't do that in the comments section.

Comment: @RichardSeal: Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to achieve that with out-of-the-box renderings.

The only one rendering that builds a hierarchical structure based on some field value is **Archive** rendering (typical archive functionality used on blogs).

[image]

You could potentially use **Tag Cloud** rendering, but it will not cover all your requirements (you can use data attributes which contains number of items with a given tag to display numbers but you will not see a list of all items which belong to this tag/category)

[image]

If I were you I would decompile **Archive** rendering and try to create a structure based on other fields. Right now it accepts only `Date` fields.

or **Tag Cloud**, you can change the facet for it (default is `SxaTags` field) right now, the only thing you have to do additionally is to render it differently (with 
 list of items under each category)